# HTTP 500 exception when configuring workflow manager, during Add-WFHost

Tags: workflow-foundation, servicebus, workflow-manager-1.x

I have an exception, when configuring Workflow Manager with the default settings.  It's not the typical 401 exception, but an internal server exception (500), I get.
I don't see things in the event log, so I am rather in the dark at this moment.  The only logging I get is pasted below:

```
[Error] [27/11/2013 12:22:25]: System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Could not successfully create management Service Bus entity 'WF_Management/WFTOPIC' with multiple retries within a timespan of 00:02:05.7804254.. The exception of the last retry is: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error..  ---> System.TimeoutException: Could not successfully create management Service Bus entity 'WF_Management/WFTOPIC' with multiple retries within a timespan of 00:02:05.7804254.. The exception of the last retry is: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error..  ---> Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServiceBusResourceOperations.CreateOrUpdateAsyncResult`1.EndGetResponse(CreateOrUpdateAsyncResult`1 thisPtr, IAsyncResult ar)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 


Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.CreateOrUpdateSubscriptionAsyncResult.OnCreateSubscription(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.AsyncCompletionWrapperCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Management.ManagementEntitiesCreator.CreateManagementEntitiesAsyncResult.EndCreateSubscription(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.BackoffRetryAsyncResult.IsolateWithRetry(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Administration.ServiceUpdateManager.CreateManagementEntities(IList`1 namespaceManagerUris, ServiceBusClientCredentialType clientCredentialType, IDictionary`2 arguments, TimeSpan retryTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.Commands.WorkflowServiceConfigHelper.SetWFRuntimeSettings(String resourceDBConnectionString, String config)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.Commands.AddWFHost.CallWFRuntimeSettings(Service wfserviceInfo, String unencryptedResourceConnectionString)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.ConfigWizard.CommandletHelper.InvokePowershell(Command command, Action`3 updateProgress)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.ConfigWizard.ProgressPageViewModel.AddWFNode(FarmCreationModel model, Boolean isFirstCommand)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? Sounds like an install gone wrong. I have run into other installation issues but never this one.

Comment: hello vasily - I didn't manage to fix that one.  I recreated a new virtual machine and there it seemed to work :s

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error on doing the Add-WFHost on Windows Server 2012. This was solved by installing WorkflowManager-KB2902007 (Cumulative Update 2).